# Where and how often to calculate ranking for posts in ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, ranking

I have a algorithm to calculate the ranking for posts on a website (uses votes, views, comments and lifespan ). I am going to be using a shared hosting provider, so I am thinking that I would start a thread in the Application_Start method of Global.asax.

Is this the only/best way to do it?

How often should I calculate the ranking? (the result will be stored in the same db table as the post.)

Would you use Thread.Sleep(*T*) to make the calculation happen every *T* often?

Comment: How long does the ranking calculation take? ASP.NET isn't the best place for long running processes. If it will take a while, you may want to run a scheduled task against the same database or even a windows service.

Comment: At the moment it takes roughly 800ms per post, as I am generating it on the fly. I will extract the method out to a stored procedure later, where it should be much faster.

Comment: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Comment: @Andrew I use the hacker news algorithm. The older something is the lower the ranking http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to calculate lifespan?) it can be calculated on the fly from start or end date at UI.

Just in case. For the rest you can use triggers at your DB. Every new post or view or something may update corresponding counter.

Comment: Cheers, looking at triggers now.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use Application_BeginRequest in global, and every  XX min do the calculation :).

This off course all depends on how your ranking data is stored, and data amount. It could be enough for a smaler site to calculate the rating on the fly when someone opens a page with ranked content and cache it for the next user.

In short it all depends on data you have to proccess, the more information you post. The more we can help.
Atm we can mostly throw out guesses

Comment: Where did you get 142 from? I mean T as in a variable of time. The ranking result will be stored in the same table.

Comment: Sorry, Font on my machine does not like Thread.Sleep(T) look like Sleep(7). Other then that, i stand by  my response :)